# Accuracy, F-Score, and Kappa Together

Tags: accuracy, confusion-matrix, cohens-kappa

What can accuracy, f-score, and kappa indicate together for a confusion matrix that each individually can't?

I get F-Score and Accuracy measure to be quite close so I feel it should be sufficient for my analysis to use just Accuracy and Kappa scores. I wonder if adding F-Score to my analysis can make it stronger.

Comment: You should not compare different coefficients' values unless you make a special rescaling (e.g. correction for chance etc.).

Comment: I don't understand your suggestion. All what I am trying to do is to look at different confusion matrix scores and understand the classification performance. In this respect, I would like to know what extra will f-score contribute to my understanding above accuracy and kappa.